# "Missing number, treated as zero" error with \includegraphics

Tags: includegraphics

I am trying to add a pdf image into my document, but whenever the code is run, it throws a "Missing number, treated as zero" error. I suspect this may be because the file name of the image contains underscores, but I am not sure how to resolve this. My code is below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx, underscore}

% File path to graphics
\graphicspath{{C:/Users/joshm/OneDrive/Documents/Research/Figures and Images/}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[hp]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Tromas_Data_With_Model_Debug_(2).pdf}
\caption{A plot of Tromas' model arranged by leaf.}
\label{fig:cartoon}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The problem are the spaces in the folder name. If you have an up-to-date distribution you can try `pdflatex-dev` instead of `pdflatex`. The next release of the LaTeX kernel (`-dev`) will have proper handling of file names with spaces. Also, the `underscore` package is causing the `_` in the file name to misbehave.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik the main problem is the underscore package -- and pdflatex-dev won't help here.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, thank you for the help, but I tried the same process after moving the file to a directory that didn't contain spaces and updating the file path and the same error still appeared.

Comment: The issue is to do with the use of the underscore package.  It causes the underscores in the file names within includegraphics to be mishandled.

Comment: I don't seem to have the rep to suggest closing as a duplicate, but I think this is answered here now: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/521007/70067